# Copy the artifact that was built to a new git repo via jenins pipeline

Tags: git, automation, jenkins-pipeline, devops, artifactory

I am trying to work on a jenkins pipeline with the below stages:

1. Fetches Code from Git repo "A"
2. Builds the code
3. Pushes the artifact to Artifactory
4. Fetch the same artifact from Artifactory (It's a Zip file format)
5. Push this Zip file to a new git repo "B"

I have steps 1-4 working and i am not sure how to accomplish step 5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

I have tried the pipeline and its working fine steps 1 through 4.I usually deploy the artifact to a app/web server as a part of step 5. This is a new scenario where step 5 involves just copying the zip to a certain directory in a new repository.

//Below is the working stages 3 and 4 for reference

```
stage('Archive Artifacts'){
            steps{
                archiveIt(                                            
                   group: 'com.abc.www',
                   name: 'www-ui-app',
                   version: "${artVersion}",
                   repo: 'www-maven-release-local',
                   credentialsId: '************',
                   includePat: './dist/prod_build_archive/*.zip'
                )
            }
        }
        stage('Fetch Artifacts'){
           steps{
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '************', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {

                sh "wget --user ${env.USERNAME} --password $PASSWORD --no-check-certificate \"https://rpo.int.net/artifactory/www-maven-release-local/com/abc/www/www-ui-app/${artVersion}/www_ui_app.zip\" "
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with 2 steps using the [Jenkins-Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in):

1. Upload the artifact to repository "A" using [`rtUpload`](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-UploadingandDownloadingFiles).
2. Promote the built to repository "B" with [`rtPromote`](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-PromotingBuildsinArtifactory) and make sure that `copy: true`.

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/promotion-example/Jenkinsfile).

Alternatively, you can use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI).

Comment: Thanks , that helps.I will try